# Formula that will pull the week day when a student is selected when selected for multiple days by the same person

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a scheduling and attendance tracker:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y2XgDolK37OfeErIb47yBIsoK0GWL8EWTLNw3lnxdwo/edit

The first two tabs, "9th Tutoring Block" and "10th Tutoring Block", are the tabs where teachers will indicate which students that they are selecting for tutoring and on which days.

The last three tabs, "Teacher1", "Teacher2", and "Teacher3",  are the tabs that are auto-populated with their tutoring attendance list. I used a query to pull that data automatically.

**Now for each student that is on the teacher tabs, I need a formula to automatically fill in the day of the week the student is supposed to be in tutoring.

The catch is that one student can be selected by the same teacher on multiple days.**

For example Student 1 may be selected by Teacher 1 for Monday and Wednesday, so that student needs to appear on the teacher tab twice, but with different day of the week data.

This is the current formula I have in cell J3

```
ifs(
$A3=index('9th Tutoring Block'!$K:$K),"Monday",
$B3=index('9th Tutoring Block'!$L:$L),"Tuesday", 
$C3=index('9th Tutoring Block'!$M:$M),"Wednesday", 
$D3=index('9th Tutoring Block'!$N:$N),"Thursday",TRUE,"")
```

This is a formuala that I was experimenting with, but could not get to work:

```
ifs(
$A3=index('9th Tutoring Block'!$K:$K),"Monday",
$B3=index('9th Tutoring Block'!$L:$L),"Tuesday", 
$C3=index('9th Tutoring Block'!$M:$M),"Wednesday", 
$D3=index('9th Tutoring Block'!$N:$N),"Thursday",TRUE,"")
```

Any advice is welcome. I'm not sure if I should be using vlookup/hlookup, index/match, an array, ifs, or a combination of the above.

Comment: Kelsey, as a suggestion, having the summary table of "Room Totals" tacked on the bottom of your two data sheets may cause you problems at some point.  It means your queries have to extend only to a specific row number, rather than to the bottom of the sheet, which is how people often write them.  Maybe put them on their own sheet, or have a summary tab for "reporting" info where they could be included?

Comment: Good idea. I'll move the room totals to a summary tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to avoid needing your columns A to D, in Teacher1, and did a fresh query from your two data tabs.  The formula I used is:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY(
               {  '9th Tutoring Block'!A3:E138, '9th Tutoring Block'!F3:F138,left("MO-"&ROW(A3:A138),2);
                  '9th Tutoring Block'!A3:E138, '9th Tutoring Block'!G3:G138,left("TU-"&ROW(A3:A138),2);
                  '9th Tutoring Block'!A3:E138, '9th Tutoring Block'!H3:H138,left("WE-"&ROW(A3:A138),2);
                  '9th Tutoring Block'!A3:E138, '9th Tutoring Block'!I3:I138,left("TH-"&ROW(A3:A138),2);
                 '10th Tutoring Block'!A3:E138,'10th Tutoring Block'!F3:F138,left("MO-"&ROW(A3:A138),2);
                 '10th Tutoring Block'!A3:E138,'10th Tutoring Block'!G3:G138,left("TU-"&ROW(A3:A138),2);
                 '10th Tutoring Block'!A3:E138,'10th Tutoring Block'!H3:H138,left("WE-"&ROW(A3:A138),2);
                 '10th Tutoring Block'!A3:E138,'10th Tutoring Block'!I3:I138,left("TH-"&ROW(A3:A138),2)},
               "select Col1,Col2,Col4, Col5,Col7 where Col6 ='"&E1&"' order by Col1,Col7")))
```

This is just a stacking of all of the required data into one temporary array, and then running a single query against it.  To make it work, I created an extra column for this array, that adds the day of the week to each data row.  I used an array formula, and the changing row number, to force it to create one value per row, but then I used LEFT to strip off the unnecessary row number.

I've put this in a tab I added to your sheet, GKTeacher1.  The same formula can be copied and pasted without change to Teacher2 and any other Teacher tabs.

Comment: Kelsey, if interested, I also did a copy of your 9th Tutoring Block sheet, to show how to use array formullas to fill the whole column, rather than copying the formulas down.  Let me know if you want any explanation on how those work.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much for the solution, your explanation of it, and your additional advice. You solved my issue AND helped me understand how it works.

Comment: With the array formula on the data tab, it is possible for it to show blanks in columns that do not have student data, so past row 138 without changing the ranges in the array?

Comment: Do you mean the way column J, in "GK9th Tutoring Block", was filling all the way down with "No", below the student rows?  I've just fixed that, by adding a test for a student name in column D, and only then checking for an assigned teacher in columns F to I.  If you mean something else, please clarify, and I'll be happy to try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({
 IF('9th Tutoring Block'!F3:F138="",,"Monday");
 IF('9th Tutoring Block'!G3:G138="",,"Tuesday"); 
 IF('9th Tutoring Block'!H3:H138="",,"Wednesday"); 
 IF('9th Tutoring Block'!I3:I138="",,"Thursday")}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again player0. This formula works perfectly. Glad to know that I was somewhat on the right track.

Comment: it should work with the previous formula (the one you dropped UNIQUE)